# Why is not selecting radio option in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have some inputs type radio:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.languages_sys.name">
  <a href="">
    <input type="radio" ng-click="changeDefaultLanguage(key)" ng-model="lng">
    <span>{{value}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

When I click on these inputs I am not getting selected radio button.

Comment: Show your angular code too..

Comment: @Muhad You know better than to post an incomplete question that doesn't include enough code to reproduce your problem. You did this yesterday and it took far too long to uncover the actual problem

Comment: I added full code to question

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a confusion in implementing radio in angular. Hope you are implementing radio to select language among the list. Let me give you example

```
   <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedlang" value="eng">
    English
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedlang" ng-value="fre">
    French
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedlang" value="sp">
    Spenish
  </label>
```

Here **selectedlang** variable contains selected language. Try above code to understand and make necessary change in your template.

Check [radio](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) implementation.

Comment: Maybe my update of question will give you some ideas

Comment: Paste your language list collection. Here why you are setting variable with ng-click. You can get selected language from variable specified in ng-model.

Answer (score 0):

html part :

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="user in users"> <input type="radio" name="userRadio" data-ng-click="getUserDetails(user)">
        {{user.title}}
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

controller part:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
    {'id' : 1 ,'title' : 'Title1', 'label' : 'Zip code', 'type' : 'xxx' },
    {'id' : 2 ,'title' : 'Title2', 'label' : 'MD', 'type' : 'title1'},
    {'id' : 3 ,'title' : 'Title3', 'label' : 'DMS', 'type' : 'title2'}
  ];

  $scope.getUserDetails = function(entity){
     // alert(entity.id);
      console.log(entity);
   }
}
```